# Using Chakra(JsRT) engine, how to use JsRuntimeAttributeAllowScriptInterrupt?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using JsRT script API interface to interact with MSIE script engine.
There is a flag called 'JsRuntimeAttributeAllowScriptInterrupt' for runtime.
How can I set callback or abort current evaluation of javascript?

I am using following JsRT C# sample.

Title : JavaScript Runtime Hosting Sample
URL : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/JavaScript-Runtime-Hosting-d3a13880

Answer (score 0):

Self reply.
There is a property "Disable" in runtime.

By setting

```
runtime.Disable = true
```

It will internally invoke

```
JsIsRuntimeExecutionDisabled()
```

to terminate current execution.

runtime will stop script execution.

Seting 'JsRuntimeAttributeAllowScriptInterrupt' flag for runtime instance required to use this function.

It works as i expected!